# Find the equation of the diametral plane that is perpendicular to the given plane.

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, conic-sections, surfaces

> Find the diametral plane of the surface
> $$x^2+2y^2-z^2+2xy-2yz-2xz-4x-1=0$$
> that is perpendicular to the plane $$x+y+z-3=0$$

I know that the diametral plane passes through the center of the surface (if exists), so I have found the center $C(3,-2,-1)$. So if we denote the plane by $$Ax+By+Cz+D=0$$ then we have $$3A-2B-C+D=0$$ and, also, as it is perpendicular to the given plane $$A+B+C=0$$ Now, I need one more equation, but cannot find it. Any help is appreciated.

$\textbf{Edit:}$ Consider the surface given by the equation
$$F(x,y,z)=a_{11}x^2+a_{22}y^2+a_{33}z^2+2a_{12}xy+2a_{23}yz+2a_{31}zx+2a_{14}x+2a_{24}y+2a_{34}+a_{44}=0$$ Then, to find the center, one may use the formula
$$
\begin{cases}
a_{11}x+a_{12}y+a_{13}z+a_{14}=0 \\
a_{21}x+a_{22}y+a_{23}z+a_{24}=0 \\ 
a_{31}x+a_{32}y+a_{33}z+a_{34}=0
\end{cases}
$$ Note that this formula can also be written in the form of partial differentiation by each variable.

In our case, this gives the center $C(3,-2,-1)$

Comment: There are infinitely many planes passing through the center and perpendicular to the given plane.

Comment: @Aretino Maybe they do have a general form?

Comment: They have in common the unique perpendicular line from the center to the plane, hence they form a pencil of planes.

Comment: @VIVID can you please show us how you've found the center?

Comment: @user376343 Edited accordingly.

Comment: @VIVID I've found $x+2y-3z-2=0.$ It is orthogonal to the given plane and passes through the center. This plane is conjugate to the direction of the normal vector $(1,1,1)$ of the given plane, but I am not sure about it 